# How can I find the default value of a property that is part of an Apple framework?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I made a [`VNRecognizeTextRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrecognizetextrequest) which is part of the Apple's [`Vision`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) framework.

```
let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest()
request.customWords = ["Weird word"]
```

The description of [`customWords`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrecognizetextrequest/3152640-customwords) says that it will be ignored if "language correction is disabled."

[image]

I assume they are talking about [`usesLanguageCorrection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrecognizetextrequest/3166773-useslanguagecorrection).

```
let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest()
request.customWords = ["Weird word"]
request.usesLanguageCorrection = true /// here
```

I could just set it to `true` myself. However, I want to know the default value of this -- **whether it will be `true` or `false` if I don't set it myself.**

[image]

I could just print it out, but it would be nice if there was something like  `Jump to Definition`:

[image: Definition of "usesLanguageCorrection"]

Comment: "Disabling this will return the raw recognition results providing performance benefits but less accurate results". This looks like it implies that the default value is true

Comment: I agree with Leo that the docs *suggest* that the value is true, but that's sloppy tech documentation. When a function parameter has a default value, the docs should state that explicitly. You shouldn't have to read between the lines for "x implies y" hints.